# Components style ignored after production build

Tags: svelte, rollup, postcss, tailwind-css, svelte-3

I have a Svelte application with Tailwindcss and Postcss configured.

In development mode everything is working well, every styles (global one and components styles) are used and working.

When I make a new production build, components styles are not used, it seems do be ignored during production build.

I add some style to my component like the Svelte documentation show and this is working well during dev local env.

```
<style>
  div {
    height: 37px;
  }

  div:hover {
    height: 72px;
    border-radius: 1rem;
  }
</style>
```

Even when I use a dedicated style file, the css bundle is totally failing and some other css properties (from tailwindcss) are not working...

I don't find inside my Rollup/Postcss configurations what seems to be wrong.

Here is my `rollup.config.js`

```js
import svelte from 'rollup-plugin-svelte';
import resolve from '@rollup/plugin-node-resolve';
import commonjs from '@rollup/plugin-commonjs';
import json from '@rollup/plugin-json';
import livereload from 'rollup-plugin-livereload';
import postcss from 'rollup-plugin-postcss';
import { terser } from 'rollup-plugin-terser';
import sveltePreprocess from 'svelte-preprocess';
import svelteSVG from 'rollup-plugin-svelte-svg';

const production = !process.env.ROLLUP_WATCH;

function serve() {
  let started = false;

  return {
    writeBundle() {
      if (!started) {
        started = true;

        // eslint-disable-next-line global-require
        require('child_process').spawn('npm', ['run', 'start', '--', '--dev'], {
          stdio: ['ignore', 'inherit', 'inherit'],
          shell: true,
        });
      }
    },
  };
}

export default {
  input: 'src/main.js',
  context: 'window',
  output: {
    sourcemap: true,
    format: 'iife',
    name: 'app',
    file: 'public/build/bundle.js',
  },
  plugins: [
    postcss({
      extract: true,
    }),
    json(),
    svelteSVG(),
    svelte({
      preprocess: sveltePreprocess({ postcss: true }),
      dev: !production,
      emitCss: true,
      css: (css) => {
        css.write('public/build/bundle.css');
      },
    }),
    resolve({
      browser: true,
      dedupe: ['svelte'],
    }),
    commonjs(),
    !production && serve(),
    !production && livereload('public'),
    production && terser(),
  ],
  watch: {
    clearScreen: false,
  },
};
```

Here is my `postcss.config.js`

```js
const cssnano = require('cssnano');
const postcssColorMod = require('postcss-color-mod-function');
const postcssPresetEnv = require('postcss-preset-env');
const postcssImport = require('postcss-import');
const postcssUrl = require('postcss-url');
const purgecss = require('@fullhuman/postcss-purgecss');
const tailwindcss = require('tailwindcss');
const postcssFontMagician = require('postcss-font-magician');

const production = !process.env.ROLLUP_WATCH;

module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    postcssFontMagician({
      variants: {
        'Roboto Mono': {
          300: [],
          400: [],
          700: [],
        },
      },
      foundries: 'google',
      protocol: 'https:',
    }),
    postcssImport(),
    postcssUrl(),
    tailwindcss(),
    postcssPresetEnv({
      stage: 0,
      autoprefixer: {
        grid: false,
      },
    }),
    postcssColorMod(),
    cssnano({
      autoprefixer: false,
      preset: ['default'],
    }),
    production &&
      purgecss({
        content: ['./**/*.svelte'],
        defaultExtractor: (content) => content.match(/[A-Za-z0-9-_:/]+/g) || [],
      }),
  ],
};
```

After hours of seeking a solution and modifying configurations I can't make it works.
I think the purgecss function is removing my component's style without conviction.

Everything seems to be OK, did I miss something?

**EDIT**

Even some JavaScript is not included in the final bundle. It's very weird

Answer (score 1):

You can check couple of things:
Is cache purged?
Does `public/global.css` include your styles (or is it `/public/build/bundle.css`)?

You can make sure that your browser don’t use cached files by changing ”versions” in your `index.html` like this:

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="/global.css?v=2.4" />
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="/build/bundle.css?v=2.4" />
  <script defer src="/build/bundle.js?v=2.4"></script>
```

Those `v=2.4` don’t mean anything, you just change/increase numbers after every build/deploy and this forces the browser to load fresh every file.

Open your `global.css` and search your style tags, do you find them. If yes then they are included and it’s cache problem. If not then it’s problem of treeshaking.

Comment: I don't have any public/global.css everything goes to public/build/bundle.css and styles tags aren't inside the file after a production build. I don't think cache is the problem, I don't have any cache on stylesheet files. Tested on private window on unused browser

Comment: Sorry `global.css` was my mistake, `bundle.css` is the right file of course. In my simple setup I have: `"build:css": "set \"NODE_ENV=production\" && tailwindcss build public/tailwind.css -o public/global.css"` (package.json), `purge: {content: ["./src/**/*.svelte","./shared/**/*.svelte"],}` (tailwind.config.js) and `svelte({dev: !production,css: css => {css.write('public/build/bundle.css');}}),` (rollup.config.js)